# Is it possible to obtain a transit visa at Heathrow Airport?

Tags: visas, air-travel, uk, transit-visas, lhr

I am an Iranian national travelling with British Airways from Tehran, Iran via Heathrow Airport, London to Shanghai, China. I will arrive at LHR on 28th at 11:55am and depart at 14:10pm without changing terminals.

If I need a transit visa, can I obtain one at Heathrow Airport?

I am scared that British Airways have stopped a few people from boarding flights.

Also, do I need a transit visa to enter the UK?

I want to do some sightseeing.

What are the chances of getting past officials using transit without visa concession?

Comment: Regarding sightseeing, you're planning to be on the ground for just over 2 hours, which is about the time we'd advice you to aim to get back to the airport. If you want to see the sights of London, try to get a window seat on the way to London and hope your flight lands from the east.

Comment: A two-hour connection isn't enough for sight-seeing anywhere in the world.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. It's specifically asking about getting a visa at the airport.

Comment: I don't spoke about visit London just i wanna fly with British airways and i have short stop in airport.also It's not  joking (djr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a "direct airside transit visa" (DATV) to connect at Heathrow, and visas are **never** issued at UK airports, **ever**.

While theoretically you could get through the international connections corridor at Heathrow undetected without a DATV, the check-in staff in Tehran is particularly responsible to make sure they don't transport you without the proper documentation. So if you don't have a DATV, you're not getting on the flight to London.

So, again, **you need a DATV**.